# Remove/Hide the block if the View is empty?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, theming

Is there any API to know if the block is empty? Basically what I'm trying to do is to hide/unset the block inside `template_preprocess_page`.

Here is my currrent code:

```
 if ($variables['page']['rail_full']) {
    foreach ($variables['page']['rail_full'] as $keys => $blocks) {
      if (isset($blocks['content']['#views_contextual_links_info'])) {
        $name = (isset($blocks['content']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui'])) ? $blocks['content']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view']->name : '';
        $display_id = explode('-', $blocks['#block']->delta);
        $block = views_get_view_result($name, $display_id[1]);
        if (empty($block)) {
          unset($variables['page']['rail_full'][$keys]);
        } 
      }
    }
  }
```

But the above code always return a `count` of `1` when I print `$block`.

The below works fine but not a good solution. I want it to be dynamic in all block as possible.

```
if (!isset($variables['node']->field_author_favorite_links['en'])) {
    unset($variables['page']['rail_full']['views_franchise_page-block_2']);
}

if (!isset($variables['node']->field_article_column['en'])) {
    unset($variables['page']['rail_full']['views_franchise_page-block_3']);
}
```

Comment: could you let me know how you have created the view?

Comment: there is a setting in views to hide block if view empty, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same behavior with "empty" fields. Unless you don't hide the fields themselves, the design/ markup still renders.
Solution for me was to filter for fields being "NOT NULL".
(Maybe it depends on the "fences"-module i have installed, too. Not sure, because not tested ...)

Comment: Wow, that did the trick for me! Thank you for sharing :-)

Answer (score 2):

By default, if a view with a Block display returns no results, it won't be rendered. That is unless you've set some "No Results Behavior" which the view will display when empty. So check to make sure it has nothing set.

[image]

So coding shouldn't be necessary unless you're trying to do something more custom. If so, you may want to clarify what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you're creating a block with a view, then the *block* will still be rendered in the markup, however the contents will be empty.

Comment: Actually **that's not true**. I created a test view with a block display that purposefully returned no results and it wasn't rendered in the region I assigned it to, not even the title. As soon as I modified the block to show results it rendered.

Comment: @apower If you are creating a block view that is simple then yes you are correct, but if you have one that has a contextual filter and the filter validates correctly, but there are no items in the result set, the block wrapper does still load.

Comment: @Chapabu's comments are absolutely correct. I am also running in the same situation